# Making text input invisible but tangible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a country dropdown filter for a search. This will allow users to search within the selected region.

Select 'Thailand' from the dropdown, 'Thailand + ' will be pushed to the search box which allows user to enter another keyword (e.g. Food) which forms into

'Thailand + Food'.

Due to technical constraints this is my only workaround creating a search filter. I am wondering can i make the selected region text invisible (Thailand +) yet when i press enter.. 'Thailand +' is part of the search results.

What i want to achieve:

1. User selects 'Thailand'
2. <strike>Thailand +' is pushed to textbox (Not visible to user)**</strike>
3. User types 'Food' in the search box
4. Both 'Thailand + Food' is in the search result

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="testfloat">
    
    <select id="quantity">
        <option selected>Select Libraries</option>
        <option value="Albanian + ">Albanian</option>
        <option value="Singapore + ">Singapore</option>
        <option value="Malaysia + ">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="Germany + ">Germany</option>
        <option value="France + ">France</option>
        <option value="Thailand + ">Thailand</option>
    
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#quantity').change(function(){
  var qty = $('#quantity').val();
  var total = qty;
  $("#ms-helperText").val(total);
});
</script>


<input type="text" id="ms-helperText">
```

Comment: Perhaps save the selected option in a hidden input, then concat that option to the search box to whatever the user typed in. Or just on the search function get the selected option value and concat it with whatever the user typed in the box, not necessary to have all the text in the search box...

Comment: Hi Lixus, that's what i am trying to do! Saving the selected option in a hidden input but...part of the typed in search! I tried 'total.style.opacity = 0;' but couldn't work.. Due to the technical constraints I have, this is the only workaround i can come out with...

Comment: So you are not able to convert you `#ms-helperText` into a `type="hidden"` form element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the selected country in the input, store it in a variable and change it accordingly.

This is how should be your code:

```js
var searchedCountry = "";
$('#quantity').change(function() {
  searchedCountry = $('#quantity').val();
  $("#preview").html(searchedCountry + " " + $('#ms-helperText').val());
});

$('#ms-helperText').keyup(function() {
  $("#preview").html(searchedCountry + " " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="testfloat">

  <select id="quantity">
        <option selected>Select Libraries</option>
        <option value="Albanian + ">Albanian</option>
        <option value="Singapore + ">Singapore</option>
        <option value="Malaysia + ">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="Germany + ">Germany</option>
        <option value="France + ">France</option>
        <option value="Thailand + ">Thailand</option>
    </select>
  <input type="text" id="ms-helperText">
  <br/>
  <div id="preview">

  </div>
```

Comment: I think the problem with this though is, that he needs it for an actual search form :) Sending the resulting value would only be possible with an AJAX request

Comment: Yes after storing it, it can be sent with an AJAX request :)

Comment: Hello, the code looks sleek! but there's a problem.. If i start typing on the text box first and then go back to do a selection on the dropdown.. The text will not get updated.. any workarounds? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JacksonLim Ok, yes of course there's, we just need to add this line `$("#preview").html(searchedCountry + " " + $('#ms-helperText').val());`  to the dropdown `change` handler, I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Concat both values into a hidden form element:

```js
// Get all needed input elements
const $country = document.querySelector( '#country' );
const $quantity = document.querySelector( '#quantity' );
const $msHelperText = document.querySelector( '#ms-helperText' );

// Event handler
function inputChange() {
  const collection = [];
  $country.value && collection.push( $country.value );
  $quantity.value && collection.push( $quantity.value );
  
  // Only add + if both inputs have a value.
  $msHelperText.value = collection.join( ' + ' );
  console.log( 'Hidden element value: ', $msHelperText.value );
}
$country.addEventListener( 'input', inputChange );
$quantity.addEventListener( 'input', inputChange );
```

```html
<select id="country">
  <option value="" selected>Select Libraries</option>
  <option value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
  <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
  <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="quantity">

<!-- the new hidden form element, that will hold both values -->
<input type="hidden" id="ms-helperText">
```

Comment: Wow, let me try this out!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to attach that value into a hidden input in html

```
<input type="hidden" id="somehiddenvalue"></input>
```